# ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/...../pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

Tags: linux, yocto, qemu, bitbake, recipe

ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/ahmed-nasr/Desktop/Linux_Customization/myPoky/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

Im building my custom image for QEMU by bitbake, and i found these problem (...do_compile exit '1')

Comment: All the interesting and diagnostic messages will be somewhere above that line. You need to quote more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Found The Solution :

Build on host machine Ubuntu version 18.04 (18.04.6 is my recommendation)

**Note :**
1- Don`t Build on 21.04 version.

2- if VBOX not run 18.04 version , use VMware workstation